# Term for a feeling of discomfort when being without your mobile

Tags: single-word-requests

I've heard it called 'no mobile phobia' or 'nomofo', but it's not really a phobia, so I'm wondering if there are any other common place terms.

Comment: My suggestion "mobile phone addiction"

Comment: ...Cold talkie.

Answer (score 4):

It is indeed called ***Nomophobia***. Here's the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nomophobia) on it:

> Nomophobia is the fear of being out of mobile phone contact.The term,
>   an abbreviation for "no-mobile-phone phobia", was coined during a 2010
>   study by the UK Post Office who commissioned YouGov, a UK-based
>   research organization to look at anxieties suffered by mobile phone
>   users. The study found that nearly 53% of mobile phone users in
>   Britain tend to be anxious when they "lose their mobile phone, run out
>   of battery or credit, or have no network coverage". The study found
>   that about 58% of men and 47% of women suffer from the phobia, and an
>   additional 9% feel stressed when their mobile phones are off. The
>   study sampled 2,163 people. Fifty-five percent of those surveyed cited
>   keeping in touch with friends or family as the main reason that they
>   got anxious when they could not use their mobile phones.
>
> The study compared stress levels induced by the average case of
>   nomophobia to be on-par with those of "wedding day jitters" and trips
>   to the dentists.Ten percent of those questioned said they needed to be
>   contactable at all times because of work. It is, however, arguable
>   that the word 'phobia' is misused and that in the majority of cases it
>   is only a normal anxiety.

While the use of "*phobia*" to describe this seems debatable, as far as official terms go, this is the closest you've got.

Comment: I guess it's similar to the term 'homophobia' which isn't an express _fear_ of homosexuals, but disliking/prejudice/hatred

Answer (score 2):

There is the term ***mobile/cell phone separation anxiety*** also. *Separation anxiety* is already a well-established term and this term is coined as a specific type of it.

There is the below infographic from T-Mobile regarding separation anxiety:

[image]

There is this brilliant and humorous idea in kickstarter called *[noPhone](https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/nophone-usa/nophone-0)* which is built specifically to alleviate the anxiety that comes along with not having a phone. There is the question "Is this a joke?" in FAQ but the answer is "No".

[image]

---

Additioanlly, there is an experiment about mobile phone separation anxiety explained in the book Cyberpsychology and New Media: A Thematic Reader (edited by Andrew Power, Grainne Kirwan). You can check it out [here in Google Books](http://books.google.ca/books?id=_UQiAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA45&dq=%22phone%20separation%20anxiety%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qSQwVPPqPJe0yATQsYCACg&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22phone%20separation%20anxiety%22&f=false).

Answer (score 1):

An alternative expression could be:

[Smartphone addiction](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/reading-between-the-headlines/201307/smartphone-addiction) :

> - Nomophobia- fear of being without your smartphone- affects 40% of the population

Source: www.psychologytoday.com